# Turning off Eclipse Validation

Tags: eclipse, validation

I want to completely switch off Eclipse validation for all languages.

This is not the same as disabling validation of various patterns, I don't want Eclipse to even try to validate.

Version is Juno.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> Click Window > Preferences and select Validation in the left pane. The
>   Validation page of the Preferences window lists the validators
>   available in your project and their settings.
>
> To disable individual validators, clear the check boxes next to each
>   validator that you want to disable. Each validator has a check box to
>   specify whether it is enabled for manual validation or on a build.

[see here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user/topics/tjvaldisable.html)

Comment: Thanks, but appears to be for Indigo.  There is no Validation section in the top level of the left pane in Juno.

Comment: It's the same in Juno 4.2.2. Look out for `Suspend all validators`. Here is the correct link: [Disable Validation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user/topics/tjvaldisable.html?cp=66_1_0_6_3)

Comment: This does not work with my JSP Files in Eclipse Juno: Those wiggly lines (e.g. HTML5 complaints) just don't want to go away. Seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 12):

It might also help to disable Validation Builders:

`Project Properties` - `Builders`

Comment: This is my ultimate answer to resolve "eclipse stuck at 67%" and "disable js validation" thanks!

Comment: Also tried that, doesn't work :(

Answer (score 10):

- Click Window > Preferences,
- select Validation in the left pane.
- Check Suspend all validators (2nd check box on the right pane for Juno)
- Click Apply, Click OK

Comment: Does not work, As soon as I open a js file it is there again, saying there is an error :(

Answer (score 2):

**Update for Mac Eclipse:**

Disable validation options as per your requirement (you may disable all also).

`Eclipse => Preferences => Validation => Disable checkbox (or Disable All) => Apply`

Reference screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Tried that! Doesn't work :(