# STS still so slow after doing all these steps

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I am using Spring 3.7.3.RELEASE on MacBook Pro Retina with 128GB SSD. While doing any kind of operations like saving the changes, refreshing the project, building the project, while debugging, while synching with VCS etc, it becomes so slow. I have already did the following things,

> 1. Unchecked all plugins in Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Startup and Shutdown except spring maven integration tool
> 2. Disabled automatic builds under Install/updated and Label Decorator
> 3. Upgraded to the latest JVM
> 4. Disabled all validations

**My laptop configuration:**

```
Model Name: MacBook Pro
Model Identifier:   MacBookPro12,1
Processor Name: Intel Core i5
Processor Speed:    2.7 GHz
Number of Processors:   1
Total Number of Cores:  2
Memory: 8 GB
Storage: 128GB SSD
```

**STS configuration:**

```
-clean
-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=6000m
-Xverify:none
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/sts.icns
-Xmx6000m
```

Please suggest me what to do to speed up STS.

Comment: You "only" have 8Gb of memory but let STS consume a large part of that, limiting the memory instead of assigning a whole lot seems smarter. Which will eventually slow down your whole system. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/how-can-you-speed-up-eclipse and also this blog https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/eclipse-having-a-slow-day-speed-it-up-in-a-few-clicks/

Comment: I don't think it is a memory problem. As after giving approximately 6GB ram I saw STS hardly using of 2GB of it though there abundance available memory. Sometimes, even it becomes unresponsive though other application runs smoothly.

Comment: Please reduce the max heap setting to something around 2GB in your setting. I would definitely not recommend to use more than that. In addition to that I would suggest to raise an issue at https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS, so that we can analyze in detail what is causing this issue for you. We need your help a bit in investigating this. Would be good to capture thread dumps while STS hangs (or is taking a long time for something) and attach them to the bug report. I am sure we will figure out what is going wrong there.

Comment: In addition to that I mentioned above, it might also be good to know more about your installation, for example if you installed additional plugins into STS or if this happens with a vanilla STS 3.7.3 distribution.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I have decreased the maximum heap size to 2GB and disabled all the plugins and validators. though the speed increased little bit but when I do the project build the remote system explorer gets started and makes the system non-responsive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had faced this issue in past, but after installing [Optimizer for Eclipse](https://zeroturnaround.com/free/optimizer-for-eclipse/) it become much faster. Otherwise you can use the latest version of Eclipse i.e 4.6 for STS it is slightly faster than the previous one and the thread blocking issue is solved here.

Comment: From https://jrebel.com/free/optimizer-for-eclipse : "As of October 2018, Optimizer for Eclipse is no longer available." Any replacements?

Answer (score 0):

Optimizer is definitely helpful but I also disabled almost all validation except for few essential ones

Click Window > Preferences and select Validation in the left pane. The Validation page of the Preferences window lists the validators available in your project and their settings.

To disable individual validators, clear the check boxes next to each validator that you want to disable. Each validator has a check box to specify whether it is enabled for manual validation or on a build.

This answer was really helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15900200/1895627